# How to get a random item from an array in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, arrays, cypress

I'm attempting to write a `Cypress` test that selects a random radio `button` answer from each group of `5` questions per page.

I'm trying to do this by programmatically choosing a number between `1- 5` and clicking on one. It is possible to get a random item from an `array` in `JavaScript`, so how to do this in `Cypress`?

This is the `array` example that I am using::

```
var myArray = ["Apples", "Bananas", "Pears"];
var randomItem = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];
```

Since `Cypress` is still in its infancy, I am having trouble finding examples on how to set up conditional statements. From what I understand of variable use in `Cypress`, if the variable is visible, it can be accessed without the necessity of defining it.

Also, I am having issues coming up with the proper conditional statement to randomly select a radio-button where the question randomizes `3-5` visible answers per each of the `5` questions per page.

```
it('selects random radio buttons',() => {           
cy.get('@mat-radio-group')
     .children() 
     .each(($matRadioGroup) => {
         cy.get($matRadioGroup).children()
            if($matRadioGroup.children <= 5) {
                   .random function?
                   .click()
            }
        })

// This code clicks through all of the buttons on the page and leaves selected the last button for every question regardless of the randomizing visible answers (Does not randomize the button selection)

cy.get('@mat-radio-group')
   .children() 
   .each(($matRadioGroup) => {
     cy.get($matRadioGroup)
         .children()
         .eq(0)
         .click()
```

There should be a way of doing this without the frowned-upon use of `if` statements in Cypress. I am a beginner developer so any tips or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

just some other thought. Since they are all radio `buttons`, there is no need to create an `array` and randomly select one of that `array`.

What you also can do is create a random number between `0` and `4`. Then combine it with the usage of `eq()`.

You already found out how you can select an array-item randomly, same way you can select a number randomly:
`Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)`.

So if I take your last part of the code and add the random selection it looks like this:

```js
cy.get('@mat-radio-group')
   .children() 
   .each(($matRadioGroup) => {
     cy.get($matRadioGroup)
         .children()
         .eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * 5))
         .click()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When using this way, I get CypressError: Timed out retrying: Expected to find element: '1', but never found it. Queried from element: <label.mat-radio-label>. Upon additional runs, that element number does change/randomize. I believe this radio button group also contains the string text question, so maybe that is the issue?