# Cypress select any value from any dropdown list

Tags: html, user-interface, testing, automated-tests, cypress

The web page contains many dropdown list.
The step is not crucial to select specific dropdown list / value.
As I just need to select any and make the Next button appear, so that I can press the Next button.

this sample defined specific dropdown list, how do I use it to select any?

```
cy.get('select').select('user-1')
```

Answer (score 1):

In Cypress, command `select` requires an argument (`value` or `values`) that identify by attribute value the item(s) included in your drop-down list.  In your example, `value` is `user-1`.

The argument of `cy.get` is a specific drop-down list too.

So a **hint for a solution** could be to develop a code that randomly takes a drop-down list in your page, then randomly takes a value between the list included in this drop-down, then pass it as argument to command `select` in Cypress.

**Related links**:

- [Cypress documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/select.html#Syntax)
- https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/03/20/working-with-select-elements-and-select2-widgets-in-cypress/
- [How to get a random item from an array in Cypress using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57616245/how-to-get-a-random-item-from-an-array-in-cypress-using-javascript)
- https://crazytesting.pl/30-days-with-cypress-day5-random-element-selection/

Comment: alright, "develop a code" , any suggestion or reference how do I start?